# ZingChart Time Series with gaps

Tags: javascript, charts, zingchart

Suppose my time series are something like this below and the dates are not always continuous  but contain gaps - in other words dates are missing. Is there a way to show these gaps in the chart. The way it works now all the various dates are connected. To find the gaps in code might not be optimal, as the sets are big and will become bigger by adding nulls in the array. Is there a way to handle this?

```
    var myConfig = {"type": "line", "series": [{"values":[
[1475929136367,0.010948905109489052],
    [1475929856367,0.038321167883211674],[1475930576367,0.0364963503649635....]}]};

        zingchart.render({ 
            id : 'myChart', 
            data : myConfig, 
            height: "100%", 
            width: "100%" 
        });
```

Comment: There is no way to handle this within ZingChart. Nulls is the only way. You only have to put one null point to drop off the line, so it doesn't seem like the general case would make your array that much bigger.